# C# writing to xml file element access problems

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to write data to an xml file from 1 numericUpDown and 3 textboxes. However, I can not access the elements of XDocument file across methods.

Below is my code with all my comments. Could you help a complete noob to xml and to the site? All recommendations for improvement welcome!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace AA
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Will be used to check if the file exists in the save directory
    byte ifexists = 0;

    //method for file creation
    public void fileCreate()
    {
        XDocument XDoc = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-16", null),
                new XElement("Group",
                    new XElement("A"),
                    new XElement("B"),
                    new XElement("C"),
                    new XElement("D")
                ));
    }
//method for file save (want to save 4 values from 1 numericUpDown and 3 textboxes, when I solve file creation problems I want to use numericUpDown value as an ID and load relevant info from the xml file
    public void fileSave()
    {
    //i tried to use serverpath which seems to be better but i couldn't get it to work so I used Application.StartupPath....
    XDocument XDoc = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\..\\File.xml");
    Group.Add(new XElement("A", nUDforA.Value));
    Group.Add(new XElement("B", tBforB.Text));
    Group.Add(new XElement("C", tBforC.Text));
    Group.Add(new XElement("D", tBforD.Text));
    XDoc.Add(Group);
    XDoc.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\..\\File.xml");}

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //this label is used to write "Saved!"after clicking the "Write" button and become invisible again after 1 second timertick
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this label is used to write "Saved!"after clicking the "Write" button and become invisible again after 1 second timertick
        lblSituation.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //first check if the file exists   
        if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath +"\\..\\File.xml"))

{
    ifexists = 1;
    fileSave();
}
        if (ifexists==0)
        {
            fileCreate();
            fileSave();
        }
        //saying the user that the file is saved
        lblSituation.Visible = true;
        lblSituation.Text = "Saved!";
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblSituation.Visible = false;
        timer1.Enabled = false;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your `fileCreate` method does not actually save a file nor return the `XDocument`. Your `fileSave` method loads a `Dosya.xml` file but saves it as `File.xml`. Your write method checks for the existence of `File.xml`.

Comment: I've edited my post as "Dosya.xml>File.xml". It was a translation error, sorry. @DaveZych

Answer (score 0):

You should use `XDoc.Root.Add` when you adding new elements.What is `Group` ? it is your first element but,you can not access it by it's name like that:

```
Group.Add(new XElement("A", nUDforA.Value));
```

First create a new Group element with A,B,C,D elements:

```
var groupElement = new XElement("Group",
                       new XElement("A", nUDforA.Value),
                       new XElement("B", tBforB.Text),
                       new XElement("C", tBforC.Text),
                       new XElement("D", tBforD.Text));
```

Then add it to your xDocument:

```
XDoc.Root.Add(groupElement);
```

If you want to update first group element with these values then you can do the following:

```
var groupElement = XDoc.Descendants("Group").FirstOrDefault();
if(groupElement != null)
{
    var newElement = new XElement("Group",
                       new XElement("A", nUDforA.Value),
                       new XElement("B", tBforB.Text),
                       new XElement("C", tBforC.Text),
                       new XElement("D", tBforD.Text));
    groupElement.ReplaceAll(newElement);
    // save the document
}
```

Note: Also you should *save* your `XML Document` in your `fileCreate` method as mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. To better explain my intended structure I modified the first part of your suggestion as this:                                  `var Employees = new XElement("Employee",
                 new XElement("ID", nUD1.Value),
                 new XElement("Name", tBName.Text),
                 new XElement("Surname", tBSurname.Text),
                 new XElement("Department", tBDepartment.Text));
    XDoc.Root.Add(Employees);`    
However, I don't want to change the 1st entry. I'd like keep saving info such as:1,Julia,Manser,Accounting--2,Adam,Clarke,Sales--so on.. @selman22